# How to prove $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}: x^2+y^2 = (x+y)^2 \Leftrightarrow x=0\lor y=0?$

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing

The question I really have is the structure and I am not sure to use pack-unpack or not.

Here is my try:

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

Assume $x^2+y^2 = (x+y)^2$

Then $x^2+y^2 = x^2+2xy+y^2$   #by definition

Then $2xy=0$

Then $xy=0$

Then $x=0\lor y=0$

Then $x^2+y^2 = (x+y)^2 \Rightarrow x=0\lor y=0.$

Now assume $x=0\lor y=0$

Assume $x=0$

Then $x^2+y^2=y^2=(0+y)^2=(x+y)^2$

Assume $y=0$

Then $x^2+y^2=x^2=(x+0)^2=(x+y)^2$

Then $x^2+y^2 = (x+y)^2 \Leftarrow x=0\lor y=0.$

Therefore $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}: x^2+y^2 = (x+y)^2 \Leftrightarrow x=0\lor y=0.$

Comment: Its totally correct.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is, essentially, "yes, your proof is correct."  As this question has no undeleted answer (and has been in this state for several years), it appears to be abandoned.  It should be closed and deleted to declutter.